# Distribution of the minimum of a random sample

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $x_i$ is a random variable with CDF $F(.)$ with a bounded support. I get a random sample $S_n=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$. Define $x_{\text{min}}=\min(S_n)$. How can I find the pdf of this random variable $x_{\text{min}}$?

Comment: You must learn LaTeX markup!

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G_n(x)$ be the cdf of $S_n$, then

$$G_n(x)=1-P(S_n > x) =1-P(X_1> x,\ldots, X_n>x)=1-P(X_1>x)\cdots P(X_n>x)=1-(1-F(x))^n$$